# Remove brackets dots and white spaces from string

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using asp.net mvc c#.This is my string

```
string filename = "excluder version(1). final"
```

I want to concatinate string with result

```
filename = "excluderversion1final"
```

How to do this? I dont want to use the javascript or jquery. Need to do it code behind

Comment: you want to remove all non-alphabetical characters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like a good candidate for `Regex.Replace`:

```
private static readonly Regex RemovalRegex = new Regex(@"\s|[().]");
...

public static string RemoveUnwantedCharacters(string input)
{
    return RemovalRegex.Replace(input, "");
}
```

Note that this will handle *all* whitespace, not just the space character, and you can easily amend the regular expression to add extra bits.

Comment: I thought about a regexp until I realized that the string is too short and there're only 3 possible characters to remove from the very tiny string

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: Well, the title talks about "white spaces". Depending on where the string comes from, that might include tabs, invisible whitespace etc.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that too, until again I realized that we're talking about file names. BTW, both your and my answers have a big issue: OP wants to remove not only the whole characters, but the content within parenthesis

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: No, look at the example - the 1 from within the parentheses is still present. And just because it's going to end up as a filename doesn't mean we need to trust that it was originally a good filesystem filename... (And heck, many filesystems *do* allow whitespace other than space in the names.)

Comment: I am just a fresher. I feel like this is best answer. But for my needs even the second reply is enough if i dont want to replace dot.  that is      filename = filename.Replace(" ","").Replace("(","").Replace(")","").Replace(".","");          thank you so much all for replying to my small question

Comment: I am not familiar with regular expression. Please get me link you have any

Comment: @BhavinBhaskaran: There's no shortage of tutorials, guides, reference docs etc for regular expressions. I suggest you start with the MSDN documentation for `Regex`.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to remove these three characters (since we're talking about small strings like file names), you can use regular `string.Replace`:

```
filename.Replace("{", "")
        .Replace("}", "")
        .Replace("(", "")
        .Replace(")", "")
        .Replace(".", "")
        .Replace(" ", "");
```

Or maybe, simplifying it:

```
string fileName = "excluder version(1). final";

new List<string> { "{", "}", "(", ")", ".", " " }
     .ForEach(character => fileName = fileName.Replace(character, ""));
```

Comment: I think you mean `(` and `)` rather than `{` and `}` (based on the sample).

Answer (score 2):

You can use String.Replace Method:-

```
filename = filename.Replace(" ","").Replace("(","").Replace(")","").Replace(".","");
```

You can wrap this inside an extension method like this:-

```
public static class StringExtention
    {
        public static string RemoveUnwantedCharacters(this string s)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
            sb.Replace("(", "");
            sb.Replace(")", "");
            sb.Replace(" ", "");
            sb.Replace(".", "");
            return sb.ToString();
        }
     }
```

You can use this as: `filename = filename.RemoveUnwantedCharacters();`

But, since there is a possiblity of whitespaces too and not just space, I guess Regex is the best answer here as answered by @JonSkeet :)

Comment: That will give a result of "excluderversion.final" - no 1 in there, but there would be a dot...

Comment: @JonSkeet - yeah didn't noticed that. Thanks! corrected. But it doesn't look good to me as it will return new string each time right..?

Comment: I don't know if `string.Replace` is optimized to avoid creating a new string if the value to replace isn't found. Note that you're still not removing the dot.

Answer (score 0):

By using regex:

```
string header = "excluder version(1). final";          
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\W+|\s");
string result = rgx.Replace(header, "");
```